# How can an Activity access a method of NotificationListenerService?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service

I have an activity class which needs to obtain the device's current interruption filter setting.

Therefore I have a `MyNotificationListenerService` class which derives from NotificationListenerService and implements onInterruptionFilterChanged().

However `onInterruptionFilterChanged()` only gets called when the interruption filter changes. When my app launches I need to find out what the current value of the interruption filter is. NotificationListenerService has a method for this which is `getCurrentInterruptionFilter()`.

My question is: how can `MyActivity` call `MyNotificationListenerService`'s `getCurrentInterruptionFilter()` when my app launches?

The OS automatically creates and starts `MyNotificationListenerService`, is there someway `MyActivity` can get a handle to that object in order to call `getCurrentInterruptionFilter()` explicitly? 
If not, then what communication mechanism should there be in order for `MyActivity` to be able to get the *initial* interruption setting from `MyNotificationListenerService`?

.

Comment: How about creating an object for `MyNotificationListenerService` class and than accessing the methods?

Comment: @Prerak. That is exactly what my question is. HOW can MyActivity access the methods of MyNotificationListenerService? As I said in the 5th paragraph - the OS creates a MyNotificationListenerService object, therefore how can MyActivity get hold of that object is what my question is all about.

Answer (score 0):

You want to bind to the service from your Activity.  The Android docs have a detailed explanation of this at http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html

Here's an example of how it would work.

**Your Activity:**

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    private MyNotificationListenerService mService;
    private MyServiceConnection mServiceConnection;

    ...

    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, MyNotificationListenerService.class);
        mServiceConnection = new MyServiceConnection();
        bindService(serviceIntent, mServiceConnection, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }

    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        unbindService(mServiceConnection);
    }

    private class MyServiceConnection implements ServiceConnection {

        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder binder) {
            mService = ((MyNotificationListenerService.NotificationBinder)binder).getService();
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
            mService = null;
        }
    }
}
```

**Your Service:**

```
public class MyNotificationListenerService extends NotificationListenerService {

    ...

    private NotificationBinder mBinder = new NotificationBinder();

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder;
    }

    public class NotificationBinder extends Binder {
        public MyNotificationListenerService getService() {
            return MyNotificationListenerService.this;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I get an exception when the activity is being created, there's a log message that the connection is null. I read somewhere (can't find the link now) that NotificationListenerService is "special" in that only the OS can bind to it.

Comment: I've updated the answer, I left out `mServiceConnection = new MyServiceConnection();` which was responsible for the null connection.   Tested it out, and I was able to successfully bind to the Service

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However I'm finding that adding this code seemingly stops NotificationListenerService  from actually working. Without the above code when the app runs NLS doesn't do anything until the user grants notification access to the app, as soon as they do that then NLS's onListenerConnected() gets called and a change to the interruption filter results in onInterruptionFilterChanged() getting called etc. However if the above code is added, then when the user grants notification access then onInterruptionFilterChanged()  does not get called then or ever.